# MySql get lowest row value and increase by 1 if row exist

Tags: mysql

I have an order_id field which should contain unique value (0 or above).

```
 $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT MAX(order_id) AS order_id FROM media WHERE playlist_id=?");
 $stmt -> bind_param("i", $playlist_id);
 $stmt -> execute();
 $result = $stmt->get_result();
 $order = $result->fetch_assoc();
 $max_order_id = intval($order['order_id']);
```

I run this query before I insert new row and I get 0 returned on first row insert which works well. However next time I want to insert new row, it returns 0 as well in which case I want to increase this value by 1, by only if at least one row already exist.

```
 $max_order_id+=1;
```

I could do this with 2 queries if I ask how many rows exist in another query. Is there a way to do this with one query?

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: Auto increment isn't an option for `order_id` ?

Comment: no, AI is on my 'id' primary column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
SELECT IFNULL(MAX(order_id)+1,0) AS order_id FROM media WHERE playlist_id=?
```